# ds_train has shape (2, 224, 224, 3) instead of (None, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I have created my own custom dataset (with 2 classes) with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ds_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/mydir/Source_Images/',
        labels = 'inferred', # from subfolders in alphabetical order
        label_mode = "int",
        class_names = ["CVS", "No_CVS"],
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        batch_size = 2,
        image_size = (224, 224),
        shuffle = True, # randomized order of images
        seed = 123, #set the seed if  train, valid images are the same when you run again   
        validation_split = 0.1,
        subset = "training"
        )
```

df_train results in:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 224, 224, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

Now, I want to visualize my data by looking at 9 images:

```
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(ds_train.take(9)):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image.numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.axis("off")
```

However, I get the following error:

line 61, in

```
plt.imshow(image.numpy().astype("uint8"))
TypeError: Invalid shape (2, 224, 224, 3) for image data
```

I'm looking for a way to resolve this, and be able to plot my images with matplotlib.

EDIT:

More importantly, it seems that the data of the data cannot be used when training the model either as I get this error:

```
   ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer EfficientNet: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(2, None, 224, 224, 3)
```

After running the Keras example code I found [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/) (where I created ds_train with the `image_dataset_from_directory` instead of the `tdsf.load()` function).

So I think there is something going wrong in the way I created the ds_train. Any resolutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are leaving the `batch_size` in, when you do:

```
plt.imshow(image.numpy().astype("uint8"))
```

With your original code you still won't be able to see 9 images because of your `batch_size`. I think it will be fine if you do it like:

No errors should be thrown like `TypeError: Invalid shape...`:

```
plt.imshow(image[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
```

Furthermore you can do following to see batch_size:

```
for img_batch_size, labels_batch_size in train_df:
  print(img_batch_size.shape)
  print(labels_batch_size.shape)
```

For your case `img_batch_size.shape` should print (2,224,224,3) where this tuple corresponds to **image tensor**.

For `input_shape` problem, you need to add your model so we can see what's wrong with `input_shape`.